# Global log out from all Stack Exchange accounts

Tags: feature-request, accounts, logout

I am having account on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3962541/losung) and [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/51382/losung). I don't have a permanent system to log in to these accounts, so I need to log out each account separately every time. So, it would be great if I could get an option to log out of all Stack Exchange accounts through a single log out option. Maybe it could be in Network Profile.

I don't know whether it a possible or helpful for others, if not just excuse me.

Comment: It'll probably be more appropriate to ask for this feature on http://meta.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If you use an OAuth provider just log out of that. If you are going to use a public computer use an incognito window beforehand.

Comment: Also take a look at [Log out of all Stack Exchange sites with linked account simultaneously](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73686/log-out-of-all-stack-exchange-sites-with-linked-account-simultaneously)

Comment: @ AstroCB : Thanks for the edit

Comment: Note: It's not working at the moment, check the posts on Meta.

Answer (score 1):

On a public computer, just clear the cache and history of the browser you are using.

Comment: Don't forget to clear the HTML5 local storage as well. That's where the info is stored for auto-login.